# Why javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:?

Tags: spring, propertynotfoundexception

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/flows/claimant/check/wireForm.xhtml @52,165 value="#{checkViewModel.check.wireInfo.originationInfo.referenceNo}": Target Unreachable, 'originationInfo' returned null on 'com.bfds.saec.domain.WireInfo'

Comment: Asking volunteers to help quickly doesn't help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

Answer (score 0):

The error just says that the value returned for `originationInfo` from your bean `com.bfds.saec.domain.WireInfo` is NULL. You need to ensure that a non-null value is returned.