# null bean in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

So I have a selectOneMenu in my user profile page. The value it targets is a field in my user profile table. That field is a foreign key of another table. Initially this value is null because the user hasn't set his info yet.

The select one menu looks like this :

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{userProfileEdit.uinfo.datBean}" >  <!-- This Value is null initially -->
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{datBeanConverter.beansList}" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean.title}" itemValue="#{bean}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The value is initially null and I'm getting this error :

```
value="#{userProfileEdit.uinfo.datBean}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

How can I go around this if I can?

Edit: My uinfo property bean is initialized in the userProfileEdit like so

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserProfileEdit implements Serializable {
    private Userinfo uinfo;
    @EJB
    private UserProfileService us;
    //...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setUser();
        this.uinfo = us.getUserInfo(username);
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: which version  of JSF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define new datBean variable and put it in value attribute like this

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{userProfileEdit.datBean}" >  <!-- This Value is null initially -->
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" />
       <f:selectItems value="#{datBeanConverter.beansList}" var="bean" itemLabel="#{bean.title}" itemValue="#{bean}"/>
   </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Then after submit form you can create uinfo object and use datBean object.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with your second answer (my bean was already instantiated). However the first one works though I had to change something so I'm gonna edit your comment, I hope you don't mind. I'm still perplex why that works and not my original code.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the second solution (sorry if that was not correct from my part). I thought you misunderstood my initial problem with it. I could be wrong so sorry if my removal of your answer was incorrect.

Comment: The problem is uinfo is null, so the solution is to initialize this object or replace, @PostConstruct method is called after constructor, so here you initialize. or use first solution

Comment: Uinfo is not null !!! Your answer is not correct that's why I edited it. Read my post again.

Comment: Oh sorry, had a pretty rough night. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it in the postconstruct method of the bean.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
...
    UserInfo uinfo= new UserInfo();
    //you will need to initialize the property datBean of UserInfo in the Constructor.
...
}
```

***Additional info:***

[@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html)

[Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please accept this question if it helped solving your problem, as this would be appreciated from other users that has the same problem.

Comment: Yes I will, I was away for 2 hours. Ima check this now.

Comment: great, don't hesitate asking any clarifications.

Comment: I'll need clarifications indeed. My uinfo bean is already instantiated (I added the code in my main post). So I'm not sure if I understood incorrectly what you said.