# <p:commandButton> referencing <p:contentFlow var="i"> throws javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'i' resolved to null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I keep getting `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'i' resolved to null` on my PrimeFaces application, when I click on `commandButton`*which is supposed to delete the image* but I just can't seem to find the reason. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) answer but nothing there is my problem. When I **remove or not click on** the `commandButton` the application works, and the `var="i"` works perfectly for all the other `DOM/PF` elements, so I'm just stuck here.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
<h:form>
    <div id="visor-imagenes">
        <p:contentFlow value="#{imageHandler.personalImgList}"
                       var="i" id="contentFlow"
                       styleClass="contentWrapp">

            <p:graphicImage value="#{fileUploadMB.image}"
                            styleClass="content"
                            onclick="clickFlow(this, event)">

                <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>
                <h:inputHidden  value="#{i.imageDescription}"/>

                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                                 action="#{imageHandler.deleteImage(i.id)}"
                                 update="contentFlow">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:graphicImage>
            <div class="caption">#{i.imageName}</div>
        </p:contentFlow>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

bean:

```
public void deleteImage(String i) {
    this.imgFacade.deleteImage(i);
}
```

I tried using `<f:param`, `<f:setPropertyActionListener`  for the `i` value in commandButton but non of these worked.

setting the `commandButton` out of the `<p:graphicImage` throws same error:

```
<p:contentFlow value="#{fileUploadMB.personalImgList}" var="i" id="contentFlow" styleClass="contentWrapp">                         
     <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                 action="#{fileUploadMB.deleteImage}"
                 update="contentFlow">
           <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>                                    
     </p:commandButton>                             
         <p:graphicImage value="#{fileUploadMB.image}"  styleClass="content" onclick="clickFlow(this, event)">
             <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>
             <h:inputHidden  value="#{i.imageDescription}"/>                                                                                             
        </p:graphicImage>                               
      <div class="caption">#{i.imageName}</div>                                                     
</p:contentFlow>
```

also, I have done overriding to the `onClick` event for the image, since **default** clicking redirected to image file.

```
       <script>
        function clickFlow(item, e) {
            if ($(item).parent().hasClass('active')) {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var text = $(item).siblings("input[type=hidden]").attr('value');
                $('.image-linker:first-child').attr('href', $(item).attr('src'));
                $('.image-linker:first-child').attr('title', text);
                $('.image-lightboxer:first-child').attr('src', $(item).attr('src'));
                $('.image-linker:first-child').click();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

the `<h:inputHidden value="#{i.imageDescription}"` is what allows to fill the `lightbox title=""` attribute dinamically.

I don't think so but, Could the `onClick` event being overridden have any effect on this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The `<p:contentFlow>` is [not](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.1/org/primefaces/component/contentflow/ContentFlow.java#ContentFlow) an [`UIData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) component. It is thus not capable of saving and restoring the iteration state during a component tree visit (as required during decode of `UICommand` component). You'd basically need to print image's unique identifier as a HTTP request parameter during render response.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                 action="#{imageHandler.deleteImage}"
                 update="contentFlow">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{i.id}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

```
public void deleteImage() {
    String i = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
    this.imgFacade.deleteImage(i);
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you.Well I had already tried this solution, but I re-checked to see if I had placed something wrong and I still get the same error.

Comment: I now see that you've placed the command button inside the image. This will result in invalid HTML. Separate them, or use a command link and put the image inside the command link.

Comment: What is weird is that I already use the `<f:param` a couple lines of code before and this works perfectly for this is how the images are rendered.

Comment: The f:param is only applied on the parent. So your current f:param is only applied on the image, not on the command. The command must have its own, exactly as shown in the answer.

Comment: The error is still shown when clicking the `commandButton` even placed out of `graphicImage`,  I update question with these details.

Comment: Get rid of `<h:inputHidden>`, it isn't making any sense in this construct. If that still doesn't work, then please post the full stack trace, so we can pinpoint the caller.

Comment: When I click directly on the image,  a `<p:lightbox` is activated to show a bigger image, the `<h:inputHidden` contains the image description. I'll update this

Comment: It is referencing `#{i}` which isn't available there during decode. Look for a different solution if the `<p:lightbox>` is causing problems.