# How to get the selected image from <p:contentFlow>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

so i have this p:contentFlow with multiple images, every image is a model that has a name and a path so what i want to do is that whenever user clicks on an image i want to pass the image(which is obviously a model) to bean and then get the path of the image...

**well my problem here is when a user clicks on the image it calls the getImagePath method and passes the image to the method but the image actually null!**

here is my code :

xhtml:

```
<h:form>

    <p:contentFlow value="#{viewer.images}" var="image">
        <p:commandLink styleClass="content"
            action="#{viewer.getImagePath(image)}">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/#{image.name}"
                styleClass="content" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:contentFlow>

</h:form>
```

and the bean:

```
    public void getImagePath(ImageModel image) {
    System.out.println(image.getPath());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this howto. Why did you publish this as a question?

Comment: @Selaron i'm sorry i forgot to use "?" at the end of my question. this is not a howto this is an actual question.

Comment: But it does in no way state what problem you have with your code. And 'Not working' is not the right addition ;-) Tried without a contentFlow?

Comment: @Kukeltje okay my bad. I've edited my question again hopefully this time i'll get an answer... btw the contentFlow has to be a part of the code the whole point is having a contentFlow. thanks...

Comment: And your PF version is? Tried the latest?

Comment: @Kukeltje my PF version is 6.2.9. and no i haven't tried the latest.

Comment: And your bean scope?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31285683/1431979