# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet

Tags: hibernate, jsf, many-to-many, propertynotfoundexception

I try to recuperate data from association ManyToMany but i can't, this is my code.

Entity Produit :

```
@Entity
public class Produit implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="Produit_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String dq;
private String icForme;
private String ich;
private String icht;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinTable(name="produit_terminal", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Produit_ID")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Terminal_ID")})
    private Set<Terminal> terminals = new HashSet<Terminal>();

//getter setter
```

Entity Terminal :

```
@Entity
public class Terminal implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="Terminal_ID")
private Long id;
private String crimpkontakt;
private String equipment;
private String geometrie;
private String dcbt;
private String icb;
private String ak;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="terminals")
private Set<Produit> produit = new HashSet<Produit>();

//getter setter
```

Class : ModuleJPADao

```
public List<Produit> parProduit(String cat){
    cat = "%" + cat + "%";
    Query query = getEntityManger().createQuery( "from "+ getPersistentClass().getSimpleName()
            +" u where u.produit LIKE :cat").setParameter( "cat", cat );
    List<Produit> module = (List) query.getResultList();
    return module;

}
```

Class : ModuleService

```
public List<Produit> tousModuleProduit(String produit) {

    if(produit!= null){
        return moduleDao.parProduit(produit);
    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

main-flow.xml

```
<view-state id="accueil" view="accueil.xhtml">
    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="moduleService.tousModuleProduit(module.getProduit())"
            result="viewScope.recherche" />

    </on-render>
</view-state>
```

file.xhtml

```
 <p:accordionPanel value="#{recherche}" var="car">

                    <p:tab title="IcForme : #{car.icForme}">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellspacing="20">

                            <p:outputLabel value="ICHT: " />
                            <p:inputText value="#{car.icht}" />

                            <p:outputLabel value="terminals : " />
                            <h:form>
                                <h:dataTable value="#{car.terminals}" var="der" >
                                    <p:column>
                                        <h:outputText value="#{der.geometrie}" />
                                    </p:column>

                                </h:dataTable>
                            </h:form>


                        </h:panelGrid>
        ....
```

i can't get the value of geometrie; i got this erreur:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/flows/main/accueil.xhtml @84,53 value="#{der.geometrie}": Property 'geometrie' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet
```

Comment: Where is your 'car' bean/getter/

Comment: what do you mean ???

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ```
> <h:dataTable value="#{car.terminals}" var="der">
>     <p:column>
>         <h:outputText value="#{der.geometrie}" />
> ```
>
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'geometrie' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet

Thus, the `#{car.terminals}` is a `Set<E>`. The `<h:dataTable>`, `<p:dataTable>` and `<ui:repeat>` components doesn't support iterating over a `Set<E>`. The `#{der}` will then basically represent the `Set<E>` itself. The builtin support for iterating over `Set<E>` will come in future JSF 2.3 version.

If it's not an option to replace `Set<E>` by a `List<E>`, then just get an array out of it as below:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{car.terminals.toArray()}" var="terminal">
```