# JSF-2.3 not finding my @Named CDI-1.2 managed bean

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, websphere, cdi, jsf-2.3

Having recently upgraded to JSF 2.3 from 2.2, I noticed that @ManagedBean was deprecated, and after some research found that I should be using CDI-1.2 managed beans and the @Named annotation.

However after changing over to @Named, the JSF pages can't find the managed bean:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @38,38 value="#{controller.telstraPass}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'controller' resolved to null

I am using Maven, eclipse and WebSphere Application Server liberty v16.0.0.4
No Idea what I am doing wrong, here are the relevant files:

Controller.java:

```
package ManagedBeans;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

import Main.FileHandler;
import Main.IBMEmployee;

@Named("controller")
@SessionScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {

    private Part telstraCustomersFile;
    private Part terminateesFile;
    private String telstraPass;
    private String termineesPass;
    private String exception;
    private String exceptionTrace;
    private FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler();
    private IBMEmployee[] potentialMatches;

    public String perform()
    {
        try {
            fileHandler.process(telstraCustomersFile, terminateesFile, telstraPass, termineesPass);
            potentialMatches = fileHandler.potentialMatches;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            exception = ex.toString();
            exceptionTrace = errors.toString();

            return ("errorPage.xhtml");
        }

        return ("searchExcel.xhtml");
    }

    public void setTelstraPass(String value) { telstraPass = value; }
    public String getTelstraPass() { return telstraPass; }
    public void setTermineesPass(String value) { termineesPass = value; }
    public String getTermineesPass() { return termineesPass; }
    public void setTelstraCustomersFile(Part file) { telstraCustomersFile = file; }
    public Part getTelstraCustomersFile() { return telstraCustomersFile; }
    public void setTerminateesFile(Part file) { terminateesFile = file; }
    public Part getTerminateesFile() { return terminateesFile; }
    public String getException() { return exception; }
    public String getExceptionTrace() { return exceptionTrace; }
    public IBMEmployee[] getExactMatches() { return fileHandler.exactMatches; }
    public IBMEmployee[] getPotentialMatches() { return potentialMatches; }
}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">   
      <h:head>
        <title>Termination Checklist</title>
        <h:outputScript name="js/scripts.js"/>      
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/PageFormat.css"/>

        Created By Jerry Boyaji
        <h:graphicImage id="IBMLogo" name="images/IBM-logo.jpg"  width="101" height="48"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body onload="enableDisableSubmitBtn()">
        <div id="ContentFrame">
            <h1>Corporate Account Termination Application (CATA)</h1>
            <h3>Excel Search: <br/> Select your spreadsheet files to upload:</h3>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <h:form id="excelInputForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
                name="UploadForm" 
                method="Post">

                Telstra Spreadsheet File: 

                <br/>
                <h:inputFile
                    id="telstraCustomers" 
                    name="telstra file" 
                    size="40" 
                    value="#{controller.telstraCustomersFile}"
                    required="True"
                    onchange="enableDisableSubmitBtn()"/>

                Password if Applicable: 
                <h:inputSecret
                    id="telstraSpreadsheetPassword"
                    value="#{controller.telstraPass}"
                    label="Password if Applicable"/>

                <br/>
                <br/>

                Termination Spreadsheet File: 
                <br/>           
                <h:inputFile
                    id="terminatees" 
                    name="termination file" 
                    size="40"
                    value="#{controller.terminateesFile}"
                    required="True"
                    onchange="enableDisableSubmitBtn()" />

                Password if Applicable: 
                <h:inputSecret
                    id="termineesSpreadsheetPassword"
                    value="#{controller.termineesPass}"
                    label="Password if Applicable"/>    

                <br/>
                <br/>

                <h:commandButton 
                    id="submit"
                    value="Upload and Continue" 
                    type = "submit"
                    action="#{controller.perform}"/>

            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MainApplication</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <description>
        State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>HTTPS Redirect Security Constraint</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>MainApplication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

Server.xml:

```
<server description="jerry's local server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>websocket-1.1</feature>
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>cdi-1.2<feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <basicRegistry id="basic">
      <user name="admin" password="****"/>
   </basicRegistry>

   <administrator-role>
      <user>admin</user>
   </administrator-role>

    <remoteFileAccess>
        <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>
    </remoteFileAccess>

    <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
    <httpEndpoint host="localhost" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="****"/>

    <webApplication id="MainApplication" location="MainApplication.war" name="MainApplication"/>
</server>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Termination-Checklist-Maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>MainApplication</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MainApplication</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Configure WASdev repository -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>WASdev</id>
            <name>WASdev Repository</name>
            <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverHome>/Applications/WebProfile</serverHome>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <!--other repositories if any-->
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided<scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.16-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.3"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"> 
</faces-config>
```

I also have an empty beans.xml file in my WEB-INF folder with my web.xml and faces-config.xml.

As far as I can see I have done everything right, I have no competing implementations of JSF or CDI, and am not using any of the scopes from the JSF packages. I have absolutely no idea why this is not working...

Comment: Try to add `jsf-2.2` feature, as I only see `jsp-2.3`.

Comment: I am using jsf-2.3 which is packaged in with my .war as you can see with my pom.xml, why would adding in a previous version fix this ? Jsp-2.3 is also required because nothing works without it ( I think because either jsf-2.3 or cdi-1.2 needs it as a provided dependency, can't remember which it was)

Comment: Your application is simple enough to run with built in jsf-2.2, which is default for Java EE 7, so just for a test, you should try to remove any external jsf libs from your war, and run with provided one by the server.

Comment: Upgraded to jsf-2.3 to make use of asynchronousity and <f:websocket>, reverting to jsf-2.3 (as an external lib) @ManagedBean annotations like I had before still works as does using the jsf-2.2 default feature

Comment: Ahh, yes that is the problem. Only provided jsf implementation works with CDI annotations. Check these pags -  [CDI integration with JavaServer Faces](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_cdi_integration.html) and [Using a Custom JSF implementation(Mojarra) with WebSphere Liberty Profile and WAS full Profile](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/devTips/entry/Using_a_Custom_JSF_implementation_with_WebSphere_Liberty_Profile?lang=en). So you either use CDI with provided, or JSF beans with custom.

Comment: @Gas is right, the CDI feature provided by WAS Liberty only has intergratration with the server-provided jsf-2.0 and jsf-2.2 features.

Comment: Well now that explains a lot !
Is it possible to use a custom CDI version which can work with my custom JSF ? I'm using this JSF:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0

Comment: @Gas, Is there any way at all I can get a CDI implementation that will work with my external JSF library (see above link), I now need CDI to make use of <f:websocket> which requires me to "@Inject" (provided by CDI) a javax.faces.push.PushContext. I haven't been able to find a JSF equivalent annotation for this, I have tried "@ManagedProperty"

Comment: or @wtlucy if you have any ideas ?

Comment: Just code it with standard websocket api without JSF...

Comment: @Gas can you give me an example of a web socket API I could use ??

Comment: Check this, you have sample application with description and code - [WebSocket sample application](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2014/12/17/websocket-sample-application/)

Comment: Thanks for your help Gas, I'll summarise this and post it up a bit later as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gas pointed out, the issue was that the inbuilt CDI feature in WAS does not work with an external JSF library.

See [my post](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/376631/implementing-jsf-23-and-cdi-together-in-websphere/?smartspace=wasdev) on IBM support page which confirms this.

A way to still make use of web sockets using JSF-2.2 is to use the Javax.websocket package as @Gas pointed out. However the limitation of this web socket implementation is that it is nowhere near as easy to send data contained in a SessionScoped ManagedBean to the client of that session only as it would have been using f:websocket from JSF-2.3 as I would have liked to do.