# implementing JSF-2.3 and CDI together in WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, websphere-liberty, jsf-2.3

I have recently upgraded to using [Oracles new JSF-2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0) which involved adding the dependency as an external library in my pom.xml as I am using maven, As opposed to previously using WebSphere Application server's (WAS) [inbuilt JSF-2.2 feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.base.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_jsf-2.2.html). I wanted to upgrade to make use of the new f:websocket feature which allows me to push messages from server to client for some clever asynchronous page loading.

But before we get into that, once I upgraded, I noticed that my @ManagedBean annotations were deprecated. After  some quick googling I found I should be using CDI annotations like @Named etc. which led me to my [JSF-2.3 not finding my @Named CDI-1.2 managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064995/jsf-2-3-not-finding-my-named-cdi-1-2-managed-bean) question, from which I learnt that I could not use an external JSF library with WAS's [inbuilt CDI-1.2 feature](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.base.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_cdi-1.2.html) together.

My issue is, according to the [JSF-2.3 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2_3-final-spec/JSF_2.3.pdf?AuthParam=1495415720_f685db946dac94cd92aedcba06c5c4a4) on the server side I need to inject a "PushContext" into a variable on my managed bean using the CDI @Inject annotation like so:

```
@Inject @Push(channel="foo")
private PushContext bar;
```

I have been unable to find a JSF equivalent annotation to @Inject which works to inject an instance into my PushContext  variable  and have tried @ManagedProperty for example. So I need to get an implementation of CDI working with JSF 2.3 to make this work.

### Things I have tried:

- I have tried using inbuilt CDI feature in WAS with the code shown in my above mentioned question.
- I have tried not using the default CDI feature, and adding a [CDI-1.2 dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api/1.2) in my pom.xml (so adding CDI as an external library) which also didn't work
- Have also tried only adding the [Javax.inject library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject/1) since all I needed the @Inject annotation as a dependency instead of CDI which also didn't work (was worth a try)

I am lost as to how I am supposed to make use of the new JSF-2.3 features in WAS if I can't get an implementation of CDI working with a custom JSF library, surely I am missing something...

I have also heard of something called "cdi-enablers" can these help me ? are they legit ? or just some hacks someone put together to make something work ?

help !!!

Comment: I've tested that the mojarra JSF 2.3 impl can be booted from Liberty when JSF and CDI are bundled with the webapp.  The instructions I followed for packaging CDI inside the app are here: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html  Note, however, that I could not get the f:websocket feature to work; it seems that requires server integration between CDI/JSF and the server's websockets impl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and forum trawling, I have concluded that getting JSF-2.3 and CDI-1.2 working together to make use of the f:websocket feature in WAS is near impossible. See [my post](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/376631/implementing-jsf-23-and-cdi-together-in-websphere/?smartspace=wasdev) on IBM support page which confirms this.

A way to still make use of web sockets using JSF-2.2 is to use the Javax.websocket package as @Gas pointed out in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064995/jsf-2-3-not-finding-my-named-cdi-1-2-managed-bean/44232868#44232868). However the limitation of this web socket implementation is that it is nowhere near as easy to send data contained in a SessionScoped ManagedBean to the client of that session only as it would have been using f:websocket from JSF-2.3 as I would have liked to do.