# My EL Expressions are not being evaluated under a MyFaces 2.3 and Spring Boot 2.0.3 application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, myfaces

I have a MyFaces application running under `Spring Boot 2.0.3`, all `Servlets` and `Context Listeners` are properly registered and configured, and apparently working. Even my `index.jsf` page is being rendered. The  tags are processed correctly on the `.xhtml` file.

The problem is that all the `EL expressions` of index.jsf page are not being processed/evaluated. No error is thrown but where I put `#{myBean.property}` is always being rendered as an empty `String`. Debugging it I see that the server code of my Managed bean is not being called.

I tried changing the el-api and el-impl libs for many versions, but no one worked. The final version I used is the `el-api 2.2` specification, following the page https://myfaces.apache.org/core23/myfaces-impl/dependencies.html

As no error is being thrown, I can't figure out where is the problem. Does anybody has this error? Is it possible to run MyFaces 2.3 under a Spring Boot application packed as a jar file?

Here are the dependencies I am using on Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    compile 'io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.5.4'

    compile group: 'org.apache.myfaces.core', name: 'myfaces-impl', version: '2.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.myfaces.core', name: 'myfaces-api', version: '2.3.1'
    compile group: 'javax.enterprise', name: 'cdi-api', version: '2.0' //CDI vem embutido no JavaEE 6, mas não no Tomcat 9

    compile group: 'org.glassfish.web', name: 'el-impl', version: '2.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.5.32'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.6'
    compile group: 'org.ocpsoft.rewrite', name: 'rewrite-servlet', version: '3.4.2.Final'

}
```

Here is the Spring configuration, to load Faces servlets:

```
@Component
open class ConfigureJSF : ServletContextInitializer {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    @Throws(ServletException::class)
    override fun onStartup(servletContext: ServletContext) {
        //necessary to myfaces be enabled and work in spring boot, once servlets are loaded dynamically.
        servletContext.setInitParameter("org.apache.myfaces.INITIALIZE_ALWAYS_STANDALONE", "true")

        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS", "true");

        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX", ".xhtml")
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD", "1")

        servletContext.setInitParameter("org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY", "com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl")
        servletContext.setInitParameter("org.apache.myfaces.CACHE_EL_EXPRESSIONS", "alwaysRecompile")

                    }

    // Register ServletContextListener, necessary for Myfaces.
    @Bean
    open fun listenerRegistrationBean1(): ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> {
        val bean = ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener>()
        bean.setListener(org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener())
        return bean
    }

    @Bean
    fun requestContextListener(): RequestContextListener {
        return RequestContextListener()
    }

    //The faces servlet
    @Bean
    open fun facesServlet(): ServletRegistrationBean<MyFacesServlet> {
        logger.info { "Criando Faces Servlet..." }
        val servlet = org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet() ;
        val servletRegistrationBean = ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.jsf", "*.xhtml")
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1)
//        servletRegistrationBean.order = 1;
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

## Edit:

I copied the dependency configuration of another project that works, and the same result occurred. So, the problem is not with the code I did paste here, and yes, with my environment, which I will start to investigate more detailed on the sequence. My problematic environment contains `JDK 8, 9 and 10` and `Tomcat 9`. My project is targeting `JDK 8`. Maybe there is some incompatibility here and this is the reason for some compiled annotations not being found, I believe I will discover the problem very soon.

Comment: I followed all this instructions too, no success. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682309/changing-faces-config-xml-from-2-2-to-2-3-causes-javax-el-propertynotfoundexcept

Comment: 1) I would not add another EL impl
2) What kind of ManagedBeans do you use? JSF Native or Spring?

Comment: @tandraschko thank you. I recently tried other EL and JSF impl and the result was the same. I Use native Managed Beans. 
As I also used the same dependencies of another project, and it not worked, I am pretty sure that the problem is on my environment. As I have JDK 8,9 and 10 installed, I just realized that my annotated classes maybe are not being found because of this, maybe. I am compiling targeting Java 8, I will test more observing the JDKs that are being used. I also use Tomcat 9. Without errors being thrown is difficult but now I think I will soon find the solution.

Comment: I added my new discovery as an edit to maybe help more users that can face the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

After days trying to solve this problem, changing and combining different codes and environments, from `JDK 8 to 10`, `Tomcat 8 and 9`, testing in `MacOS` and `Windows 10`,from the `JSF 2.1` implementation of `MyFaces` to the brand new `JSF 2.3` implementation supporting `CDI`, deployed this last one on a [WildFly](http://www.wildfly.org/) server, I just noticed, on my expensive 32'' high-resolution display, that my `Managed Bean` was named with `indexBean`using a stranger character `i` with small dots on its top of, it was a diarised `ï` that I don't know how it had placed or typed there. **That was the reason my managed bean was never found no matter what configuration I used.**

I noticed this character on MacOS. On my Windows it seems harder to notice it. I think it's because of font differences, not hardware.

[image: The strange ï that cost me a week]

I am ashamed but I will not delete this question. May this can help someone in the future. Programming and life problems are like this: most of the times the error is in the less expected place.

Lesson learned.