# @Inject not working in @FacesConverter after upgrade to JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, ejb, jsf-2.3

I migrated a Primefaces 6 application to JBoss EAP 7.4 and upgraded to Primefaces 10 and JSF2.2 to JSF2.3. After this migration, the @Inject we had in the FacesConverter is not being initialized and thus returning null. This question might be duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447140/1918516), the proposed answers did not resolve my issue.

Below my current project structure.

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
            xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
            version="2.3">
    ...
</faces-config>
```

**MyConverter.java**

```
@FacesConverter(value = "MyConverter", managed = true)
@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
public class MyConverter implements Converter {
...
   @Inject
   private MyBean myBean;
}
```

**MyBean.java**

```
@Stateless
@Named
public class MyBean{
...
}
```

**Jsf23Activator.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConfig(version = FacesConfig.Version.JSF_2_3)
public class Jsf23Activator {

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
             version="4.0">
    ...

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.validator.ENABLE_VALIDATE_WHOLE_BEAN</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I have not created a **beans.xml** as it is not required with newer versions as far as i know. Also when creating one, i got the common error:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408:
> Unsatisfied dependencies for type MyDao with
> qualifiers @Default

1. I got it work for the converters by injecting with `CDI.current().select(MyBean.class).get();` but for me this is just a workaround
2. Another approach would be to make a @Named out of the MyConverter and use following in my jsf, but that would be ideal for JSF 2.2 not 2.3 :

   <h:inputSomething ...>
   <f:converter binding="#{myConverter}" />
   </h:inputSomething>

Comment: i am currently using following dependency jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec . This is provided by JBoss 7.4  So my issue is with JSF 2.3, but i don't seem to find what i might be doing wrong.

Comment: Hmmm I am using Jboss EAP 7.4 and my @Inject work fine in my converters?
```java

Answer (score 2):

The missing part of the implementation, was the beans.xml file which I intentionally did not use as starting from version 1.1 it is not mandatory, as mentioned in my question as well.

It looks that in order to inject inside a FacesConverter the creation of the following beans.xml file is needed as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all"
       version="2.0">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Jboss 7.4 EAP and my @Inject works fine inside my converters.  Here is my example converter.  Then again I DO have a beans.xml in my WEB-INF/ folder.

```java
@FacesConverter(forClass = AnnulmentReason.class)
public class AnnulmentReasonConverter extends AbstractEntityConverter<AnnulmentReason, Long> {

   /** ApplicationScoped cache */
   @Inject
   EntityCache<AnnulmentReason, Long> cache;

   @Override
   protected AnnulmentReason getObjectById(final Long id) {
      final Map<Long, AnnulmentReason> map = cache.getMap();
      final AnnulmentReason ar = map.get(id);
      return ar;
   }

   @Override
   protected Long getObjectId(final AnnulmentReason entity) {
      return entity.getId();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks actually identical to the way i have implemented it. I am  missing beans.xml , of which i am aware of, but that should not be mandatory with never versions.  I was trying to avoid the usage of beans.xml as this causes me other issues with my Beans.

Comment: I would say give beans.xml a try to see if that is the cause of your issue.  It may be a bug in Jboss EAP.