# Eclipse jsf managedBean javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

In a simple non maven jsf project i'm having this error **SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /form_tour.xhtml @13,49 value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}"**  **Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null** . I checked the bean class and the xhtml and everything looks fine to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>A Simple JavaServer Faces 2.0 View</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel value="working" />
        <p:inputText value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}" />
        <p:commandButton value="ok" />
    </h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Managed bean:

```
package com.fabio.bean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TourBean {

    private String kindOfTour;

    public TourBean() {

    }

    public String getKindOfTour() {
        return kindOfTour;
    }

    public void setKindOfTour(String kindOfTour) {
        this.kindOfTour = kindOfTour;
    }

}
```

I am using `javax.faces-2.2.8.jar` and `primefaces-6.1.jar` inside the `lib` folder in `WebContent`, they both properly appear under l`ibraries->web app libraries` in `java resources`. I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) but everything regarding the first point (my error) seem to be alright.

complete error log:

```
Nov 28, 2017 4:52:46 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase execute
WARNING: /form_tour.xhtml @12,49 value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}": Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /form_tour.xhtml @12,49 value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}": Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(Unknown Source)
at        org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:146)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:168)
... 37 more

Nov 28, 2017 4:52:46 PM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /form_tour.xhtml @12,49 value="#{tourBean.kindOfTour}": Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(Unknown Source)
at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getConverter(ComponentUtils.java:146)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:176)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier [tourBean] resolved to null
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:168)
... 37 more
```

Comment: Sure there are not errors in the logging about the bean **not** being constructed or violating certain 'rules'? Please check, I think there are

Comment: If i create any other managed bean i have the same error, if i refactor the bean into another jsf project that works with other beans this one doesn't. I've added the complete error log in the post.

Comment: Well if add simple ManagedBean classes and try to use them in a project where others were already working it gives me error, i'm thinking it has something to do with Eclipse ide

Comment: I ended up reinstalling Eclipse it's now working ..