# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException using p:graphicImage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having this problem and I don't know why is this happening, I tried so many things but... no success, thanks for your help.

this is the problem:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet [Faces Servlet] lanzó excepción
java.io.IOException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /catalogoAdmin.xhtml @16,40 value="#{catalogoBean.image}": Propiedad [image] no hallada en el tipo [beans.CatalogoBean]
    at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:43)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
```

and this is my code:

**Method Bean**

```
public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
            String filename = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("nombre");
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\images/", filename)));          
        }
    }
```

**xhtml**

```
<h:form id="formImg">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{catalogoBean.image}"
                style="height:150px; width:150px;">
                <f:param name="nombre" value="ram.png" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Read all in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable?

Comment: Can you provide the full backing bean code including class declaration to check the name ?