# Attribute that can be null in JSF form

Tags: java, jsf-2, cdi, el, propertynotfoundexception

In a JSF form there is:

```
<h:inputText value="#{personBean.person.personDetail.attribute}" />
```

The entity `Person` is loaded from database on `PostConstruct` annotated method. However, the attribute `personDetail` of `Person` instance can be null. Thereby, when the input is filled and form is submitted, an exception is throwed (more specifically `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: (...) Target Unreachable, ''personDetail'' returned null`).

I searched and found some excellent examples to solve this exception, such as:

- [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

But, I think that issue is different. The `person` instance is found and its instance attribute can be null.

I've also tried to set a new instance of `PersonDetail` when it is null on `PostConstruct` method, but thereof the issue becomes a persistence problem because the "object (`personDetail`) references an unsaved transient instance".

So, how to treat this issue?

---

### Source

Short backing bean :

```
@Named(value = "personBean")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonBean {

    (...)

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        person = personService.findById(1L);

        // throw -> TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
        // if (person.getPersonDetail() == null) {
        //    person.setPersonDetail(new PersonDetail());
        // }
        (...)
    }
}
```

Short entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    (...)

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pessoa", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PersonDetail personDetail;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

-

```
public class PersonDetail {

    private String attribute;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the first part of the solution by instanciating the **personDetail** when it's **null** ,the second part is to check before inserting in database

> if the personDetail.getAttributes != null then insert it else insert
>   null

Comment: The problem is that the following exception is throwed even before the view is rendered: `TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`