# Target Unreachable, identifier 'growlT' resolved to null

Tags: jsf

I want JSF error messages in pop up window instead of inline. It seems there is no easy way in JSF so using primefaces growl component.https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml

But getting this error:
Target Unreachable, identifier 'growlT' resolved to null

**Managed Bean**

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@SessionScoped

@ManagedBean(name="growlT")
public class GrowlView {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
```

**XHTML:**

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">Message:</td>
                <td style="width: 5px">&#160;</td>
                <td><h:inputText styleClass="inputText" id="message1"
                        value="#{growlT.message}">
                    </h:inputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <h:commandButton styleClass="commandButton" type="submit"
        value="Submit" id="growlT1" actionListener="#{growlT.saveMessage}" update="growl">
    </h:commandButton>
```

Could anybody help me out?

Comment: There is no growl in the code you posted. Nothing PF related at all btw...

Comment: oh and 'update' does not exist on an `h:commandButton`

Comment: I did not copy code for growl 
growlT is the managed bean:  
@ManagedBean(name="growlT")

Comment: yeah update does not exist but it's giving error before commandbutton  on 
<h:inputText styleClass="inputText" id="message1"
                        value="#{growlT.message}">
                    </h:inputText>

Comment: That might be happening but it is in no way PrimeFaces or its growl related. Search forcall the Q/A with similar topics like the error you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)