# Cannot Reach CDI Backing Bean With JSF 2.2 on WildFly 21

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, wildfly, cdi

I have been following [this](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2020/04/jsf-23-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven.html) tutorial to setup JSF on Eclipse version 2020-09 (4.17.0) with JAVA-14 and Maven on Wildfly-21.0 server on Windows 10. After completing the instructions on the page, I can browse to my index.xhtml page, but I cannot reach the backing bean when I submit the form. I get the following error instead:

```
[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,61 value="#{bean.input}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,61 value="#{bean.input}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:64)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:71)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1110)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1011)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1322)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:733)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:229)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:608)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:159)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1456)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:355)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1468)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:400)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:261)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1308)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:53)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.2.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:62)
at org.glassfish.jakarta.el@3.0.3.jbossorg-2//com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:160)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
... 70 more
```

In eclipse my project's properties, the "Project Facets" I can't set JavaServer Faces version to 2.3 because I get a "Cannot change version of project facet JavaServer Faces to 2.3". So I opted for version 2.2 instead. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) stack overflow post, something may be wrong with my CDI implementation.

Any suggestion on how I can fix this issue and move forward?

Thanks in advance!

My POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tanvir.project</groupId>
<artifactId>SudokuSolver</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Sudoku Solver</name>
<description>Webapp for solving sudoku puzzles</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My WEB-INF/beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

My WEB-INF/faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <!-- JSF configuration here. -->
</faces-config>
```

My Backing Bean:

```
package tanvir.project.sudoku;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    private String input;
    private String output;

    public void submit() {
        output = "Hello World! You have typed: " + input;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Finally, my xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
>
    <h:head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="input" value="Input" />
            <h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.input}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":output" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        <h:outputText id="output" value="#{bean.output}" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insdead of using jakarta.jakartaee-api version 8.0.0 as mentioned in the tutorial, I used version 9.0.0. This required me to import jakarta.inject.Named insdead of javax.inject.Named in my Bean.java to use @Named annotation. The problem got fixed (can now refer to backing bean using EL statements) when I set jakarta.jakartaee-api version to 8.0.0 in the POM file.