# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException from service to dao

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hope I use the appropriate format, firt time asking here.
I have the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bg.spring.service.impl.ProduitServiceImpl.ajouterProduit(ProduitServiceImpl.java:45)
    at main.Pg.main(Pg.java:21)
```

I've already looked up [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable) and other links to solve my problem but i think my problem lies in not understanding the Spring technology properly (maybe something to do with @Autowired or isntantianting an objet that shouldn't be)
So here is the code i'm using

produitServiceImpl

```
package com.bg.spring.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.bg.hibernate.model.Produit;
import com.bg.spring.dao.ProduitDao;
import com.bg.spring.service.ProduitService;

@Service
public class ProduitServiceImpl implements ProduitService {
    @Autowired
    private ProduitDao produitDao;

    public void setProduitDao(ProduitDao produitDao) {
        this.produitDao = produitDao;
    }

    public ProduitServiceImpl() {
        super();
    }

    public ProduitServiceImpl(ProduitDao produitDao) {
        super();
        this.produitDao = produitDao;
    }

    @Override
    public Produit getProduit(int id) {
        return produitDao.getProduit(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Produit> getAllProduit() {
        return produitDao.getAllProduit();
    }

    public ProduitDao getProduitDao() {
        return produitDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void ajouterProduit(Produit produit) {
        if (produit != null) {
            produitDao.ajouterProduit(produit);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public List<Produit> getProduitsByCategorie(int idCat, String nomProduit, Double prix) {
        return produitDao.getProduitsByCategorie(idCat, nomProduit, prix);

    }
}
```

PrduitDaoImpl

```
package com.bg.spring.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Property;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.bg.hibernate.model.Produit;
import com.bg.spring.dao.ProduitDao;

@Repository
public class ProduitDaoImpl implements ProduitDao{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public ProduitDaoImpl() {
        super();
    }

    public ProduitDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super();
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public Produit getProduit(int id) {
        Produit produit = (Produit) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Produit.class, id);
        return produit;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<Produit> getAllProduit() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Produit> produit = (List<Produit>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
        createCriteria(Produit.class).list();
        // or below query
        /*
         * @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Produit> produit =
         * (List<Produit>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
         * "from Produit").list();
         */
        return produit;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void ajouterProduit(Produit produit) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(produit);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();    
        session.close();
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Main

```
package main;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import com.bg.hibernate.model.Produit;
import com.bg.spring.service.ProduitService;
import com.bg.spring.service.impl.ProduitServiceImpl;

@ComponentScan
public class Pg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Produit pdt = new Produit("batterie3", 3, "text4", "http://fhifoezf.com", 3, 45.00);
        ProduitService pdtServ = new ProduitServiceImpl();
        pdtServ.ajouterProduit(pdt);
    }
}
```

spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">
    <!-- support spring annotation -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- support annotation transaction -->
    <tx:annotation-driven
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- declare datasource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boutique_avec_tarif" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
    <!--Hibernate session factory configuration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- load hibernate configuration file -->
        <property name="configLocation"
            value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <!-- where to find the ORM classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan"
            value="com.bg.hibernate.model" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- service -->
    <bean id="produitService"
        class="com.bg.spring.service.impl.ProduitServiceImpl" />
    <bean id="categorieService"
        class="com.bg.spring.service.impl.CategorieServiceImpl" />
    <!-- dao -->
    <bean id="produitDao"
        class="com.bg.spring.dao.impl.ProduitDaoImpl" />
    <bean id="categorieDao"
        class="com.bg.spring.dao.impl.CategorieDaoImpl" />
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bg</groupId>
  <artifactId>bg</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>bg Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
  
  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jsf2.version>2.2.10</jsf2.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysqlconnector.version>5.1.34</mysqlconnector.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- hibernate 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- database pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql java connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysqlconnector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>jsf-spring-hibernate</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
  
  
  
  <!-- <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>bg</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
-->
```

Comment: It looks to me like your `ProduitServiceImpl` is being created by you, not by Spring, so the dao is not autowired into it.

Comment: @khelwood are you saying that I shouldn't instantiate the produitServiceImpl in the main class ?

Comment: Yes. Objects created by you using `new` don't get their dependencies autowired into them because Spring doesn't know anything about them.