# JSF 2.0 PropertyNotFoundException ManageBean

Tags: jsf, propertynotfoundexception

When i navigate from page A to page B, **sometimes **Target Unreachable, identifier 'aController' resolved to null error happend.
Here is my Code

```
home.xhtml
action="#{aController.xClick}"

@ManagedBean(name ="aController")
@ViewScoped
public class AController{
xClick(){ navigation to B }
}
```

I also check solution from this page but no one works for me
[Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

I suspect that because it's a ViewSope, the bean was destroyed when page A was shut down, and the system didn't have time to render page B. Is that possible?
Since this error occurs very rarely, changing to a different scope does not guarantee that the problem has been resolved. Is there any other way?

Comment: action="{#aController.xClick}" or action="#{aController.xClick}"?

Comment: @Asgar Yes i edited content of post to be action="#{aController.xClick}"

Comment: @BalusC i use navigation-rule in file faces-confirm.xml. Is something wrong?